# Не работает js, работает только в консоли

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять почему данный скрипт не работает, а работает только в консоли

```
$('.imdb br').remove();
$('.kp br').remove();
```

Comment: Потому что скрипт находится и выполняется в таком месте страницы, где соответствующих DOM-элементов еще нет. Спасибо. Наши представления - каждый четверг.

Comment: А как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отложить выполнение до окончания загрузки документа.

```
$(function() {
  $('.imdb br').remove();
  $('.kp br').remove();
});
```